# Changing the colour/transparency of a div on rollover or using an imagemap

Tags: css, image, imagemap

I have a map which is one image. I need to have five hit areas on that image and when you rollover one of those areas, that div / part of the image / imagemap needs to go grey.

I don't want to use multiple images - I want to keep the map as one image.

Can anybody please help me - I've been searching most of the day for a solution and can't find one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward solution is probably an image map using [maphilight](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/). You can find an example there with the [code available here](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/).

Comment: Hey Marcel - absolutely brilliant. Did the trick. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @Tony: Since you're new here you might like to know, if you find an answer acceptable you can click the tick to the left of the answer.