# How can I show the outline of an area of a map of an image (html, javascript)?

Tags: javascript, image, dictionary, area, outline

If you take a quick look at the two links below, you'll see most people want to get rid of the outline around the area of a map on an image.  I see this occurs on the MAC OS X platform, exclusively.

[Removing outline on image map area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821724/removing-outline-on-image-map-area)

[How do I get rid of this border outline for my image map areas when clicked (OS X Chrome Only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351827/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-border-outline-for-my-image-map-areas-when-clicked-os-x)

However, what I want to do is show the outline in multiple browsers and change it's color and width.  I tried but to avail.  I created a style for an id.  Didn't work.  I tried using a class and that didn't work.  I set an inline style and that didn't work, either.  And I attempted it on both the map and area tags, by the way.

As of now, I use a gif to "border" the area when clicked.  But it would make things so much easier if I could take advantage of the built-in shape attribute to highlight the area clicked.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This answer looks interesting:

[Changing the colour/transparency of a div on rollover or using an imagemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429041/changing-the-colour-transparency-of-a-div-on-rollover-or-using-an-imagemap)

Links to here: http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Internet Explorer do not respect CSS for the area outlines. You can solve this by blocking the default handing of the `mousedown` event. If using jquery, something like

```
$('area').bind('mousedown',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

would take care of it for all image maps on the page.

Also take a look at my plugin: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster which will let you easily handle outline (and other) effects on mouseover and click events.